# How/when does Windows link private key to imported certificate?

Tags: windows, public-key-infrastructure

When creating CSR on Windows (using built-in certificate store), I found some weird behaviors:

1. When I use enrollment policy, but then extract CSR and sign it somewhere else, on import the certificate is not linked with the private key.
2. When enrolling certificate on VPN (using AD template), sometimes the resulting certificate exists in the store, but is not linked if I get off VPN too quickly (~5-10 minutes).
3. When using .inf file to generate CSR, sometimes after importing the certificate it's not linked with private key.

On all occasions, running "certutil -repairstore" fixes the issue, but it's hard to make all users learn to use it.

I'm interested in how/when Windows searches for private key on certificate import, and what rules are there for linking with private key.

Steps tested:

1. Double-click on the certificate.
2. Click on the "Install Certificate..." button on it (bottom of the "General" tab).
3. The Certificate Import Wizard will popup, click on the "Next" button;
4. On the Wizard Certificate Store window, click on “Place all certificate in the following store”.
5. Click on browse..
6. Check Show physical stores.
7. Expand Personal folder.
8. Select Registry.
9. click on Ok.
10. and then click on Next.
11. Confirm the required actions by clicking on the "Finish" button.
12. You should get an information (popup window) that the certificate was successfully imported, press the "OK" button of that window.

Comment: How you import signed certificate?

Comment: Does it matter? Should it matter? Is there a difference between opening the cert and clicking "Import" and importing from mmc? (and just to be clear, I'm importing PEM .cer, not .pfx).

Comment: yes, it does matter, hence a question.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that if you ask such question it does matter, but frankly I would appreciate you discussing the differences if you know them. I've hit this behavior quite a number of times during my years using Windows, and it's not like I'm consistent with ways to import the cert. What's worse, I can't exactly reproduce the issue on a whim (if I could, I would open MS support case...). For case (1), I am opening the cert, selecting "install", then pointing to Personal store; other cases I can't reproduce on purpose.

Comment: @Crypt32, I updated the question with steps that occasionally lead to issues in case (3). I also didn't mention that in case (2), enrollment policy is used.

Comment: BTW, what OS version you are running?

Comment: Windows 10, build 19042.

Comment: @Crypt32, any ideas?

Comment: Replace steps 4-8 with selecting either, automatic or Personal store (you really don't need to go so deep and it may cause issues). And before installing the certificate, check if corresponding entry exist in Certificate Enrollment Requests folder (in certificate manager).

Comment: No change, same behavior. And doesn't address (2) at all, since it's automated.

Comment: If it is automated, you should use `certreq -accept` or `certreq -user -accept` which will force certificate response association with private key stored in enrollment requests.